# Overwrite checkpoint files from tf.train.Checkpoint.save

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

In the example below, I subsequently call `root.save(path_to_checkpointfile)` and it auto-increments the filename each time. Each file is huge, and I want to just overwrite with the latest. I don't see any `kwarg` or property I can set to achieve this. Does anyone know of a way?

```
root = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                               model=model,
                               optimizer_step=tf.compat.v1.train.get_global_step())
```

Comment: I think you can't overwrite check point, but you can delete the previous one and save new checkpoint

Comment: yeah i know i could add a line of code to monitor and delete but was hoping there was a more integrated solution in TF to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Using tf.train.CheckpointManager, you can specify how many checkpoints it needs to keep at any given point of time using the argument "max_to_keep".

This keeps replacing the oldest checkpoint and saves the new one once it reaches the maximum number of checkpoints to be saved.

Please refer below link for details:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint